# MySQL fastest way to search by DATE if a record exist

Tags: mysql, date, search, select, optimization

I have found many way to search a mysql record by DATE

**Method 1:**

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE datetime LIKE '2015-01-01%' LIMIT 1
```

**Method 2 (same as method 1 + ORDER BY):**

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE datetime LIKE '2015-01-01%' ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1
```

**Method 3:**

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-01 23:59:59' LIMIT 1
```

**Method 4:**

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE DATE_FORMAT( datetime, '%y.%m.%d' ) = DATE_FORMAT( '2015-01-01', '%y.%m.%d' )
```

**Method 5 (I think is the slowest):**

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE DATE(`datetime`) = '2015-01-01' LIMIT 1
```

What is the fastest?

In my case the table has 1 million rows, and the date to search is always recent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fastest of the methods you've mentioned is

```
SELECT id 
  FROM table 
 WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-01 23:59:59'
 LIMIT 1
```

This is made fast when you create an index on the `datetime` column. The index can be random-accessed to find the first matching row, and then scanned until the last matching row. So it's not necessary to read the whole table, or even the whole index.  And, when you use `LIMIT 1`, it just reads the single row. Very fast, even on an enormous table.

Your other means of search apply a function to each row:

- `datetime LIKE '2011-01-01%'` casts `datetime` as a string for each row.
- Methods 3,4, and 5 all use explicit functions like `DATE()` on the contents of each row.

The use of these functions defeats the use of indexes to find your data.

Pro tip:  Don't use `BETWEEN` for date arithmetic because it handles the ending condition poorly.  Instead use

```
 WHERE datetime >= '2015-01-01' 
   AND datetime <  '2015-01-02'
```

This performs just as well as `BETWEEN` and gets you out of having to write the last moment of `2015-01-01` explicitly as `23:59:59`. That isn't correct with higher precision timestamps anyway.

Comment: I have found this can cause the database to cast the column to match the literal type (date) thus obviating any index.

Comment: @Bohemian, having done tonnage of this in MySQL 5.1+, I've never had the problem you mention. MySQL's query planner tries to cast constants to the same type as columns, and only if that won't work casts columns to the type of constants. A correctly formatted date string casts to `DATETIME` just fine.

Comment: Thx! Let's say I have old record in this table (2010,2011,etc) and I always search for recent date (like today,yesterday), will be faster if I add **ORDER BY datetime DESC**? example `SELECT id FROM table WHERE datetime >= '2015-01-01' AND datetime < '2015-01-02' ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1`

Comment: If you have an index on `datetime` a range scan with `LIMIT 1` should be about the same speed with or without `ORDER BY` or `ORDER BY DESC`.  MySql doesn't have any reverse-order indexing capability, but it does have the capability to find the *last* matching value as well as the first in an index lookup.

Comment: @OllieJones -- I beg to differ.  (1) only method 3 is optimized for an index starting with (`datetime`).  (2) MySQL does optimize `ORDER BY foo DESC LIMIT 10`.  You can see the difference by doing `FLUSH STATUS;` before a `SELECT`, then do `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Handler_read%';` afterwards.  Note that one of the values will show either the number of rows in the table (not optimized), or a number approximating the LIMIT value (optimized).

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way, assuming there's in index on the datetime column, is a variant of method 3 except *both* range values are datetime literals:

```
SELECT id FROM table
WHERE datetime BETWEEN '2015-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2015-01-01 23:59:59'
LIMIT 1
```

Using literal of the same type as the column means there won't be any casting of the column to perform comparison, giving the best chance of using an index on the column. I have used this in production to great effect.

Comment: Not strictly just literals.  Any "constant expression" works -- such as `NOW() - INTERVAL 2 HOUR` or `CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH`

Comment: @rick sure, as long as the expression's type match the column exactly. For example, while `NOW()` returns a datestamp, `CURDATE()` returns a date, which would require a cast somewhere.